# Axios api post request returns HTML instead of JSON in production(GAE) (reactjs + express)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, axios

I'm using reactjs and express server and deployed my app to Google App Engine.

On the development side, I could successfully get the API response in JSON format but after deploying to GAE, I could only get some default HTML as a response.

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="icon" href="./alpha.jpg"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="description" content="ABCD"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./alpha.jpg"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/><title>ABCD</title>
<script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.7a273cc2.js"></script>
<link href="./static/css/main.4fa4d373.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

I've tried to compare the API status in the Network Tab. (screenshots below). I noticed that the Response Header is different (or rather, some headers are missing in the API request made at the production side)

I confirmed that the API request works on the postman as well.

Where am I going wrong? Please help me!

`server.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
var cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
console.log("Inside server.js >>> listening on PORT", port);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({ origin: "*", credentials: true, methods:  ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']})); 

app.post("/set", (req, res) => {
  const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    ca: process.env.REACT_APP_CERT,
    cert: process.env.REACT_APP_CERT,
    key: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY,
  });

  try {
    const instance = axios.create({
      httpsAgent,
    });

    const options = {
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_PRED,
      method: "POST",
      credentials:"include",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
      },
      data: {
        w: req.body.w,
        h: req.body.h,
        g: req.body.g,
        a: req.body.a,
        i: req.body.i,
        m: req.body.m,
      },
    };
    instance(options)
      .then(async (response) => {
        res.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => res.send(err));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("GG", err);
  }
});
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //const path = require('path');
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("serving static index.html file.. >>");
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "build"))); // using middleware
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html")); // serving the static file
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));
module.exports = app;
```

`frontend-side API request(reactjs)`

```
async function req(postdata) {

  const instance = axios.create({});

  const options = {
    url: "/set",
    method: "POST",
    credentials:"include",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    },
    data: postdata,
  };
  const data = instance(options)
    .then(async (response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("e:", e);
    });
  //return requ;
  return data;
}
```

`Network Tab screenshots`

`Development`

[image]

[image]

`Production`

[image]

[image]

Also, in the `package.json`, I have added this line which seems to have effect in api request only in the local environment.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Comment: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` - yes, that is correct, since you only need to proxy in development

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the issue.

Since the problem was lying on the production side, I was going through the files that were only uploaded to GCP for production purposes. One such file is the `app.yaml`.

The configuration I had set (by blindly copy-pasting the contents from somewhere else on the internet  ) in the `app.yaml` file is as below.

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16

handlers:
  # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$
  # Catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

includes:
- credentials.yaml
```

This part `url: /.*` meant that any request being sent will fallback to `index.html` by default and that was why I had received HTML as the response upon calling the API!

So, I had to change the configuration file like below. (Remove * from `url: /.*`)

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16

handlers:
  # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$
  # Catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

includes:
- credentials.yaml
```

And that fixed the issue for me!